# How to resolve CORS error when fetching data in React Native with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, react-native, web, fetch

im beggining at web world, and have my first monster issue (maybe it's simple but, as said, im beginner here)

I'm trying do develop a app to help some players track a online feature of one game, when opening page at navigator nor postman, it returns correctly, the link is:
https://ddda.lennardf1989.com/api/v2/grace/Playstation4

Well, when i try to fetch it, an cors error are returned and on my research the 'solution' config  ("mode": "no-cors") results on a 200 response, but without data, im on 2 days at this problem :X, i've tried using await and .then to console the response, but without success

here is what im doing on my initial screen, tried to add a button to force aditional triggers and look into consoles

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

let result: string = "initial value"

export default function App() {

  let [post, setPost] = React.useState(null);
  let [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  async function callData() {
    console.log("tentando")
    const ur = fetch("https://ddda.lennardf1989.com/api/v2/grace/Playstation4", {
      "headers": {
        "content-encoding": "gzip"
      },
      "mode": "no-cors"
    }).then((resp) => {
      console.log("Resp:\n", resp)
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log("ERRO:\n", error)
    });
    console.log("foi")
    console.log(ur)
    return ur
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    callData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={ styles.container }>
      <Text style={ styles.text }>{ result }<br/>full result(post):<br/>{ JSON.stringify(post) }</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <div>
        <p style={ { color: "green" } }>{ count }<br/>{ result }</p>
        <button onClick={() => callData().then((resp) => {
          if(resp != null){
            setCount(resp)
          }
        })}>
        {/* <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}> */}
          Clique aqui
        </button>
      </div>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 50,
    color: (result == "true") ? "green" : "red"
  }
});
```

ty for your attention <3

As said, i've tried the code below and change some headers but, without success;
I accept any uses of axios or another invoke type, returning the data is more important